# How do I create an annotation in Java and access variables it creates?

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I'm using Spring Boot to create a pretty standard REST service.  Part of that means that a lot of methods will return pages of results, so the input into the method will require page number, page size, etc - e.g.:

```
    @GetMapping(
            value = "",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity readAll(
            @RequestParam("pn") Integer pageNumber,
            @RequestParam("ps") Integer pageSize,
            @RequestParam("sc") String sortColumn,
            @RequestParam("so") String sortOrder
    ) {
```

Then in the method itself we'll validate the parameters (e.g. make sure page size < 100, sort column is an allowed value, etc).  Then convert the values into something useable - e.g. create a Sort object from column and order, and then a Pageable object from the page number, page size and sort object.  That finally gets passed into the JPA repository to return a page of results.

Since this pattern is going to get repeated over and over, I'd like to just make an annotation that encapsulates all of this, but I'm not sure how to convert the 4 RequestParam variables into a single Pageable object, or how to access that object created in the annotation in the method body.

I've tried some basic Annotation work, e.g.

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ServicePageSizeValidator.class)
public @interface ServicePageSize {
    Integer DEFAULT_MAX = 100;
    String max() default "100";
}

class ServicePageSizeValidator
        implements ConstraintValidator<ServicePageSize, Integer> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServicePageSizeValidator.class);

    private Integer max = ServicePageSize.DEFAULT_MAX;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final ServicePageSize annotation) {
        try {
            max = Integer.valueOf(annotation.max());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.warn(
                    "Exception caught trying to parse page size " +
                            "constraint {}.", annotation.max(), e
            );
            max = ServicePageSize.DEFAULT_MAX;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Integer pageSize,
                           final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        try {
            if (pageSize == null) {
                throw new InvalidPageSizeException("Null page size.");
            }
            if (pageSize > max) {
                throw new InvalidPageSizeException(
                        "Page size " + pageSize + "larger than maximum " +
                                "allowed (" + max + ")."
                );
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Invalid page size.", e);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And that generally seems to work, but it's operating only on a single parameter, and just failing the whole annotation if the parameter is wrong - there's not way for me to access information about the validation in the method assuming it passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @DrTeeth, Spring already provides a great Pagination functionality, so I would stick with it, because it gives you options that you can also use with Repositories. Pageable is definitely very useful.

Generally speaking, you can perform this kind of validation using the JEE Validation API. Also, you can use Spring Resolvers to provide the params in every controller that needs them, in a very easy way. Let me give you an example. First of all, let's create a class that maps your params:

```
public class Pagination {
    @Max(100)
    int pageNumber;

    int pageSize;
    String sortColumn;
    String sortOrder;
}
```

As you can see, I'm already using Validation API. You can add the capability to your Spring Project by adding this dependency in your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

For the example's purposes, I've only added the validation on page number.
You can now create an interface. I'll explain it's use later.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface PaginationConfig {
}
```

This will tell Spring that it can expect the usage of PaginationConfig as a method's parameter's decorator.
It's now time for our resolver:

```
public class PaginationResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        return methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(PaginationConfig.class) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(
            MethodParameter methodParameter,
            ModelAndViewContainer modelAndViewContainer,
            NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest,
            WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory) throws BadRequestException {
        Pagination pagination = new Pagination();
        HttpServletRequest request
                = (HttpServletRequest) nativeWebRequest.getNativeRequest();

        try {
            pagination.setPageNumber(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pn")));
            pagination.setPageSize(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ps")));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new BadRequestException();
        }
        pagination.setSortColumn(request.getParameter("sc"));
        pagination.setSortOrder(request.getParameter("so"));

        return pagination;
    }
}
```

It is bounded to the interface we just created, and it reads the parameters values from the request, creating a Pagination object. Note that the validation is not happening, yet. We are just telling Spring how to read those values, and catching the NumberFormatException, so we can translate it in a custom Exception (that I've called BadRequestException in this example and that I would map on BAD_REQUEST HTTP Response code).

We're almost done. We now have to add some configurations:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(
            List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new PaginationResolver());
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

In this way, we are telling Spring that it has to use out custom resolver and that is has to validate methods' parameters.
It's now time we go into our controller. I'll give you an example:

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping
    public String validateAndPaginate(@Valid @PaginationConfig Pagination pagination) {
        return "hello world " + pagination.getPageSize();
    }
}
```

Things to be noted:

- we need to use @Validated at class level;
- we need to use @Valid at parameter level;
- we are decorating the parameter with @PaginationConfig, the interface we created. Spring knows how to find the values that needs to bind in that object, because we've told it to use our resolver;
- we are using the Validation API, so everything will be validated based on the annotations we've put into Pagination class;
- if a validation fails, Spring will give us a 500 error, but you can easily map it into everything you want.

Comment: This is a really good answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This might still be reasonable to keep open as a question, as there are probably similar situations for other annotations that are needed.  But for pagination at least Spring Boot apparently has me covered.

(external link): https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-paging/

Essentially:

```
ResponseEntity readAll(Pageable pageable)
```

will work, and there are a variety of ways the URL parameter names can be configured, e.g. in application.properties:

```
spring.data.web.pageable.size-parameter=size
spring.data.web.pageable.page-parameter=page
spring.data.web.pageable.default-page-size=20
spring.data.web.pageable.max-page-size=2000
```

or via annotation:

```
ResponseEntity readAll(
    @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 20) Pageable pageable
)
```

I'm going to leave this as open, and this as not the accepted answer as I feel like the more general question of how to do this right is still valid.  But it looks like the answer is probably to create a class that will self-map request parameters to itself, and then use annotations on that single object passed in to configure it.

Comment: Yep, as I suspected, someone would come up with a good generic explanation.  Use Gregorio's answer for that.